# how to get url an object with chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to get url an object when I right clicked. There is some code to search youtube as below. But I want to right click a video on youtube homepage and get url and open on new tab with embed video.

```
function searchyoutube(e){

    var searchstring = e.selectionText;

    chrome.tabs.create({url: "http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + searchstring})
}

chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Search Youtube for \"%s\"",
    contexts:["selection"],
    onclick: searchyoutube
});
```

And this is my code to fix.

```
function searchyoutube(e){


    var YTid= e.url //this is to get url the element
    var embedurl=newURL.substr(newURL.indexOf("=")+1,11);
    chrome.tabs.create({url: embedurl})
}

chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Search Youtube for \"%s\"",
    contexts:["selection"],
    onclick: searchyoutube
});
```